# Want to find occurrence of PatientUid across tables

Tags: sql-server, database

I have PatientUid primary key in Patient table and there are few more tables like Patient Address,Contact Info,---- in which i am using it as foreign key. I want to search the occurrence of one particular PatientUid across the tables in my DB

Comment: You want to find the occurence(no of entries of one Particular PatientUID) in child tables(PatientAddress,ContactInfo). Am i right? It means in your child tables there exist of more than one entry for PatientUID. Please confirm the same.

Comment: there are multiple tables that may or may not contain particular PatientUid. I want to check , 121212 patientUid is in PatientAddress,ContactInfo,PatientDemographic and other child tables.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct:
Find No_of_Occurences for one child table(PatientAddress)

```
select PatientUID,count(PatientUID) as No_of_Occurences
from PatientAddress
group by PatientUID
```

Likewise do for all your child tables(ContactInfo)

Then club everything using UNION ALL operator

```
select PatientUID,count(PatientUID) as No_of_Occurences
from PatientAddress
group by PatientUID
union all
select PatientUID,count(PatientUID) as No_of_Occurences
from ContactInfo
group by PatientUID
```

Then the total No_of_Occurences across all tables in DB can be found as below

```
select PatientUID,sum(No_of_Occurences) as No_of_Occurences
from
(
select PatientUID,count(PatientUID) as No_of_Occurences
from PatientAddress
group by PatientUID
union all
select PatientUID,count(PatientUID) as No_of_Occurences
from ContactInfo
group by PatientUID
) as all_tables
group by PatientUID
```

Use where clause in the final query to search the occurrence of one particular PatientUid of your choice.

Comment: I am newbie in database.this is helpful for me.
if there exists more than 10 tables then using union all will not be that much efficient i guess.

Answer (score 0):

select
    tab1.name as [referred_table] ,
    col1.name as [referrenced_key_column] ,
    tab2.name as [primary_table],
    col2.name as [primary_Key_column]
from  sys.foreign_key_columns fkc

inner join sys.objects obj on obj.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
inner join sys.tables tab1 on tab1.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
inner join sys.columns col1 on col1.column_id = parent_column_id  AND col1.object_id = tab1.object_id
inner join sys.tables tab2 on tab2.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
inner join sys.columns col2 on col2.column_id = referenced_column_id AND col2.object_id = tab2.object_id

where obj.name like '%Patient%' and col2.name like '%PatientUid%'